# how to add a mouse listener in JAVA?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, mouse, listener

```
private class Board extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int w=getWidth();
        int h=getHeight();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

The following code draws the grid:

```
        g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, w, h));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, h/3, w, h/3));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, h*2/3, w, h*2/3));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(w/3, 0, w/3, h));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(w*2/3, 0, w*2/3, h));
```

The following code draws circles and xs by visiting elements in the array List:

```
        for(Shape shape : shapes){
            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.draw(shape);
        }
    }
}

public void addMouseListener(MouseListener ml){

    // HOW CAN I ADD A MOUSE LISTENER HERE? 

}
```

Comment: You've just done it. What do you want the mouse listener to do?

Comment: If that `addMouseListener(MouseListener)` method is in your `Board` class, which is a subclass of `JPanel`, you are overriding the method. Just make your `Board` class implement `MouseListener` and then do `addMouseListener(this)` in your constructor.

Comment: This method is supposed to add the mouse listener passed to board. it is not working when I run it for some reason. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that `implements` the  `MouseListener` `interface` as so:

```
   public class CustomMouseListener implements MouseListener{

      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         statusLabel.setText("Mouse Clicked: ("+e.getX()+", "+e.getY() +")");
      }

      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      }

      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      }

      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
      }
   }
```

You want define each of those methods based on the action the method represents (which are self explanatory).  The `MouseEvent` object will have all the info you need related to the mouse (ex.  x and y position of mouse).

Now you want to add this new `MouseListener` to a `JPanel` (which in this case is your `Board` class):

```
  //JPanel panel = new JPanel();      
  Board panel = new Board();
  panel.addMouseListener(new CustomMouseListener());
```

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_mouse_listener.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Create your class which implements MouseListener, and pass it by addMouseListener method... ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the class implements MouseListener.
you need to add the unimplements methods.
and here you go :)
you got few new methods:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) // method calls when mouse clicked
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) // method calls when mouse pressed
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) // method calls when mouse relesed
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) // method calls when the mouse curser getting into the component's geometry
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) // method calls when mouse curser getting out of the component's geometry
```

hope it helped you :)